# Why is sqlite telling me "out of memory"?

Tags: c, multithreading, sqlite

I'm experimenting with sqlite3. I'm intending to use it in a multithreaded application to tackle all the locking and atomicity of the data shared between threads.  To keep speed up and because I don't need the data saved between program runs, I'm trying to use an in-memory database that will most of the time contain < 100 rows, at worst < 500 rows.

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with libsqlite3 version 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open_v2("file::memory:?cache=shared", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, NULL);

    /* This should never ever happen! */
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return(1);
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE Players (id int, ip varchar(15), x int, y int);", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

For the sqlite3_open line, I've tried tons of variations and I have two problems.  When I try these variations, I get an "Out of memory" error in the section I ironically commented as "should never happen":

```
rc = sqlite3_open_v2("file::memory:?cache=shared", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, NULL);
rc = sqlite3_open_v2(":memory:", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, NULL);
```

When I try this simpler line, it defies the documentation by making a file on the disk called "file::memory:?cache=shared":

```
rc = sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &db);
```

What on Earth am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` and `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` flags.

You need the `SQLITE_OPEN_URI` flag to enable URI filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLite3 as an IPC mechanism doesn't sound practical. It would seem more practical to create a socket and use your loop back interface to communicate between threads. Also if you don't need to distribute on a windows platform check out D-bus.

I wouldn't use databases to share information between threads either. Databases are used to store large sums of data, perhaps you should look into serializing.

[protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is a good library for serializing in C or C++.